# Sizing problems for different Android devices

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I am currently making an app to fit onto two separate devices: Lenovo ideapad A1 (7"), and a Samsung GALAXY Player 5.0 (5").

I originally started on the ideapad and have been placing all of my XML files into my `/layout` folder. Everything displays just fine on the ideapad, but when I switch to the 5" device, the views become too big.

I have been using this website to try to learn what to do: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

My problem is that from what they show here, both of my screens fall within `/layout-large/`, but the Galaxy 5 will also fall into `/layout`.

Right now I only have XML files in `/layout`, so why the heck would it look good on the ideapad and not on the Galaxy 5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you optimize for one screen, you can put the layout in any folder. The whole wisdom of multiple layout folders is that the Framework will choose the right one. In your particular case, Samsung Galaxy Player has 800x480 pixels resolution, while Lenovo Ideapad has 1024x600 pixels.

As explained at http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#DeclaringTabletLayouts, you can put the 7" layout into `res/layout-sw600dp`, and keep Galaxy Player XML in `res/layout`, or `res/layout-480dp`. Note that **dp** suffix here compensates for pixel density, therefore the 5" devices like Galaxy Note with 1280x800 at 285 ppi will also fall into `res/layout-480dp` category.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using images in hdpi folder then you have to provide images for mdpi folder and also the layout-normal xml for better UI.

Comment: Thanks, but its not an image. It's simply the spinner's drop down arrow. It is HUGE.